# deserialize nested json data c#

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

I am using javascriptserializer to deserialize json data. I am stuck on how to parse this data and assign the value to a variable.

**json:**

```
  {
    "data1": {
"EntityList": "Attribute",
"KeyName": "AkeyName",
"Value": "Avalue"
    },
    "data2": {
        "Id": "jsdksjkjdiejkwp12193jdmsldm",
        "Status": "OK"
    }
}
```

I need to assign the values of EntityList, KeyName in data1 to a variable. I read this json string into a variable data

**c#:**

```
var data = "json string"; //variable with json string
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic drecord = jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(data);
```

I am trying to parse this nested json into 2 variables EntityList & KeyName.

Comment: I am always using Json.Net. But can't you just do "drecord.data1.EntityList" and "drecord.data1.KeyName" to get to the variables. I must be missing something

Comment: Hi @PeterFromCologne, I tried that previously and that did not work.

Comment: HI @user25407 what library for deserialization did you use?

Comment: Hi @OxQ, System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correct so it must be smth like this:

```
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        dynamic record = jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(data);
        var data1 = record["data1"];

        var entityList = data1["EntityList"];
        var keyName = data1["KeyName"];
```